# Mysql join in create view command

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I want to create a view of a few columns from different tables.

What work´s (only the select command):

```
select linie.nummer,
       linie.von,
       linie.nach,
       zeiten.letzte_abfahrt 
from linie 
  left join zeiten 
    on linie.nummer=zeiten.Linie;
```

What doesn't work:

```
create view as 
select linie.nummer,
       linie.von,
       linie.nach,
       zeiten.letzte_abfahrt 
from linie 
  left join zeiten 
    on linie.nummer=zeiten.Linie;
```

Is there anything special in MySql? I looked many examples and didn't find the mistake...

Comment: what was your error?

Comment: Why's Oracle tagged? Do not tag products not involved!

Comment: @pala_ ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as select linie.nummer,linie.von,linie.nach,zeiten.letzte_abfahrt from linie lef' at line 1

Comment: You're missing the name of the view to create.

Comment: `create view VIEWNAME as ...`

Comment: @Barmar sorry, i am really blind.... ;) thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the view_name to the Script

```
create view view_name as 
select linie.nummer,
       linie.von,
       linie.nach,
       zeiten.letzte_abfahrt 
from linie 
  left join zeiten 
    on linie.nummer=zeiten.Linie;
```